# copy a fabric js canvas data to another canvas

Tags: javascript, canvas, html5-canvas, fabricjs

Is there any way to copy a fabric js canvas data to another fabric js canvas with all function of fabric js

```
 ctx.drawImage(sourceCanvas, x, y, width, height);
```

this function is only copying the image not the data or functions of first canvas.

Answer (score 1):

just convert source Canvas to JSON and then render that JSON to Destination Canvas.

Comment: Fabric js provides default functions to convert the canvas to JSON as well as create the canvas from JSON.
Refrences
> To convert canvas object to JSON:
http://fabricjs.com/docs/fabric.Canvas.html#toJSON
> To create canvas from JSON:
http://fabricjs.com/docs/fabric.Canvas.html#loadFromJSON

Answer (score 1):

**1. Use `fabric.Object.clone()`**

```
    var _clipboard;
    canvasOne.getActiveObject().clone(function(cloned) {
        _clipboard = cloned;
    });
    canvasTwo.add(_clipboard.clone());
```

*See detailed example at http://fabricjs.com/copypaste*

**2. Serialization/deserialization**

```
    var objectConstructor = object.constructor;
    var json = object.toObject();
    var objectCopy = objectConstructor.fromObject(json);
```

For `fabric.Image`:

```
    var objectCopy = new objectConstructor();
    objectCopy.setOptions(json);
    objectCopy.setSrc(objectCopy.getSrc());
```